# Stack Driver Monitoring Costs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

Currently I'm getting charged for $0.5 per day per environment. We have 4 environments and all per day it costs $2

We don't have any traffic at all as we are still in development phase.

When I try to disable Stack Monitoring API, it says it will disable few more api's which isn't expected.
[image: Warning for other services]

I saw that "google.monitoring.v3.MetricService.ListTimeSeries" has a request count of 1M per month in the metrics and I don't have from where this is getting triggered.

[image: Requests metric]

I see stack driver monitoring api costs are per 1000 calls and it can easily push my budgets to the edge.

Is it possible to find out from where this is getting triggered?

Comment: Where did you found this mtric request count ? Please provide the link if possible. Please also provide links to the documentation you consulted.

Comment: On clicking "Manage" in Stackdriver monitoring api, It took me to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/monitoring.googleapis.com. There once i click on metrics,  I can see these details.

Comment: Thanks - There's a possibility to change a total amount of requests / min but some services that rely on them may stop working, If you described in more detail what you want to run on GCP I can try to help you optimize it and get better idea about future costs. Keep also in mind that there's a free qouta for monitoring services, have a look at [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing).

Comment: I have no idea where that is getting triggered. Vpc access api I'm using it from pretty long time. Suddenly these calls started showing up on all of my environments. Does google offer any free support on gcp? I see only paid plans exist unfortunately. Atleast if i can find out which service is triggering monitoring api calls, I can check further.

Comment: Since this is billing related then you may try [contacting billing support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing).

Comment: I contacted them but they asked me to post on SOF as its technical

Comment: Have you tried [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Btw, thanks for checking in. I just got a doubt that it could be from new relic connections. I tried unlinking the account and waiting to see the requests pile up or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out that the issue is with NewRelic monitoring.
I gave access to NewRelic sometime back for all my projects and once I revoke the access, it stopped showing the costs!

It would be great if there is an option on gcp which resource is consuming and what is triggering it.

Comment: Hey, I am facing similar problem, Not sure where the requests are coming from. Were you able to find it anywhere ?

Answer (score 1):

Source can be tracked this way

'APIs & Services' -> Library
Search for 'Strackdriver Monitoring Api' and click
Click 'Manage' on the next screen
Click 'Metrics' from the left-hand side menu
In the 'Select Graphs' dropdown, select "Traffic by Credential" and click 'OK'

You will either see newrelic or a service account email or a unique id. That unique ID is the unique ID of the service account used.